# How open a link from a PreferenceBundle editing .plist?

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist

I'm developing a PreferenceBundle of a tweak. I would to add a `PSLinkCell` that opens a link (in Preferences or in Safari, doesn't matter).

I tried with this one, but nothing appears in the new page clicked by the `PSLinkCell`:

```
....
<dict>
<key>cell</key>
<string>PSLinkCell</string>
<key>isURL</key>
<true/>
<key>label</key>
<string>Buy me a beer/coffee!</string>
<key>URL</key>
<string>http://....</string>
</dict>
....
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a link from within a preference bundle.

You are thinking of the jailbroken version, `PreferenceLoader`.

Try this link: http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/PreferencesSpecifierPlistFormat#Using_PSLinkCell